# Name does not exist in namespace error in XAML with VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm new to WPF and trying to figure out how bindings work.

I've created a new namespace and added a class with a parameter-less class since the class can not be a subclass or have parameters to be instantiated in the xaml. The local reference I assume is correct since intellisense came up with it and correctly found the `Model2` class. However, I get an error saying that `Model2` does not exist in the m3 namespace. Did I miss something?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:simpleBindingExample.m3"  
 Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:Model2  x:Key="m2"/>
 </Window.Resources>
 <Grid>        
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Model2.vb**

```vb
Namespace m3
  Public Class Model2
     ' auto-implemented properties
     Public Property X As Double
     Public Property Y As Double
     Public Sub New(Optional x1 As Double = 0, Optional y1 As Double = 0)
        X = x1
        Y = y1
     End Sub

  End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Actually the error that I saw when I tried your example was that there was not a valid constructor for Model2 which has to do with the fact that you have a constructor with optional parameters. If you create a constructor without them it will compile correctly.

Comment: I think the error changes every time I run it. Today, it says it cannot create an instance of Model2. Having an error like "not a valid constructor" would be less cryptic. I had gotten that earlier then found out that I can't have parameters so I set them to be optional which got rid of the error previously. I removed the optional parameters and it did work. Thanks. Hopefully vs2013 fixes the error logic.